# Prevent MacPorts from installing pre-built package?

Tags: macports

I am trying to instal libiconv with MacPorts. I need to build it to run in OS X 10.5 while my Mac is running 10.6. So I added this like to `macports.conf`:

```
macosx_deployment_target 10.5
```

That supposedly force MacPorts to build the port with 10.5 SDK. However, the installed libraries still contain `LC_DYLD_INFO` load command which is available only in 10.6.

I reinstalled the port with -v option and find that it downloads and installs a pre-built package without compiling. The package obviously was built on a 10.6 machines.

The question is: how can I force MacPorts to built the port on my machine with my settings? Thanks.

Edit: I am building x86/x64 universal binaries with this command:

```
sudo port -v install libiconv +universal
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of MacPorts 2.1.0, there is a new setting called `buildfromsource` in the configuration file `/opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf` that controls the use a pre-built archives:

```
# When to build ports from source. Default is 'ifneeded', which downloads an
# archive if available or builds from source otherwise. 'always' has the same
# effect as -s on the command line, and 'never' is likewise the same as -b.
#buildfromsource    ifneeded
```

Answer (score 23):

Duh! I've looked up and down for the better part of the day. And right after I posted the question, I find it out myself.

Add `-s` to `port` command and it will pull and compile the source locally:

```
sudo port -s -v install libiconv +universal
```

Comment: I know that one.