# Setup Macports on an offline machine

Tags: macos, macports, dpkg

I need to install dpkg for my mac and the easiest way I have seen for doing that is to install Macports. Unfortunately the machine I want to install it on is not connected to the internet.

Is there a way to download dpkg and its dependencies for macports and install the packages on the offline machine?

I have seen people mention to set it up on an online machine and move the whole macports folder, however the only machine I have online is running a different OSX version which could cause issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to download all sourcefiles using

```
sudo port fetch rdepof:dpkg
```

and then copy everything in (`/opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/`) to the offline machine and put it in the same folder there.

Then you should be able to build `dpkg` using

```
sudo port install -s dpkg
```

The `-s` option forces macports to build from source. ([Prevent MacPorts from installing pre-built package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319314/prevent-macports-from-installing-pre-built-package))